# Как реализовать алгоритм

Tags: алгоритм, cookie, javascript

Друзья, помогите реализовать алгоритм в js:

1. Eсли в куки нет переменной 'banner',
2. то класс блока с баннером 'banner' отображается(.show).
3. Иначе(Если есть), то ничего не делается(display:none по умолчанию).
4. Прописать переменную 'banner' в куки.
5. Сначала.
    Это для баннера, который должен выскакивать лишь раз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно как то так, единственное баннеру задать ID, а не класс:

```
function getCookie(c_name) {
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        var c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start != -1) return true;
    } return false;
}

if (!getCookie('banner')) {
    document.getElementById('banner').style.display="block";
    document.cookie='banner=true; path=/; expires=Mon, 01-Jan-2020 00:00:00 GMT';
}
```

Фиддл: http://jsfiddle.net/rDQ33/1/

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).